# How to make desktop icons on Openbox?

Tags: desktop-environments, openbox

So, I am making an DE for me, and I want to be able to place items on the desktop. How would I do this, exactly? (nautilus -n on startup isn't working)

Comment: Does it work if you start `nautilus -n` manually ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pcmanfm`, `pcmanfm-qt` or `spacefm` to handle the desktop.
The last two also allow you to open file with the associated MIME application so you can use another file manager as your default.

Quote from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCManFM#Desktop_management :

```
Desktop management

The command to allow PCManFM to set wallpapers and enable the use of desktop icons is:

pcmanfm --desktop

The native desktop menu of the window manager will be replaced with that provided by PCManFM. However, it can easily be restored from the PCManFM menu itself by selecting Desktop preferences and then enabling the Right click shows WM menu option in the Desktop tab.
Desktop preferences

If using the native desktop menu provided by a window manager, enter the following command to set or amend desktop preferences at any time:

$ pcmanfm --desktop-pref

It is worthwhile to consider adding this command to a keybind and/or the native desktop menu for easy access.
Creating new icons
```

So add `pcmanfm --desktop &` to the Openbox autostart.

And it is worthwhile to consider adding `pcmanfm --desktop-pref` to the Openbox (right click) menu, if you want to use that by enabling it in the `Desktop Preferences`.

Same commands but with `spacefm`/`pcmanfm-qt` instead of `pcmanfm` for the others two.

Also `nemo` and `desktopfolder` can handle the desktop.
But they don't let you set the background there is a blanck screen, and you can't use the Openbox menu.
`desktopfolder` may not even start.

There are also `idesk` and `rox-filer` https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox#Desktop_icons.

I tried `idesk` you have to manually set the icons.
It doesn't reflect the desktop folder.

Nautilus doesn't have desktop management since GNOME 3: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158#instructions.